# Using LINQ, how would you filter out all but one item of a particular criteria from a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I realize my title probably isn't very clear so here's an example:

I have a list of objects with two properties, A and B.

```
public class Item
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<Item>
{
    new Item() { A = 0, B = 0 },
    new Item() { A = 0, B = 1 },
    new Item() { A = 1, B = 0 },
    new Item() { A = 2, B = 0 },
    new Item() { A = 2, B = 1 },
    new Item() { A = 2, B = 2 },
    new Item() { A = 3, B = 0 },
    new Item() { A = 3, B = 1 },
}
```

Using LINQ, what's the most elegant way to collapse all the A = 2 items into the first A = 2 item and return along with all the other items? This would be the expected result.

```
var list = new List<Item>
{
    new Item() { A = 0, B = 0 },
    new Item() { A = 0, B = 1 },
    new Item() { A = 1, B = 0 },
    new Item() { A = 2, B = 0 },
    new Item() { A = 3, B = 0 },
    new Item() { A = 3, B = 1 },
}
```

I'm not a LINQ expert and already have a "manual" solution but I really like the expressiveness of LINQ and was curious to see if it could be done better.

Comment: But why `A = 2` `B` is `0` in the expected result? I thought that collapse might refer to sum all A2 `B` values into a single item...

Comment: So you want to only collapse where `A = 2` and then only take the first item with `A = 2`?

Comment: What if items with `A=2` are not sequential?

Comment: Sorry, bad wording on my part. It's just taking the first item, not really collapsing like a sum of all items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
var collapsed = list.GroupBy(i => i.A)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.Key == 2 ? g.Take(1) : g);
```

The idea is to first group them by `A` and then select those again (flattening it with `.SelectMany`) but in the case of the `Key` being the one we want to collapse, we just take the first entry with `Take(1)`.

Comment: Do you happen to know how GroupBy works internally? Is it using GetHashCode and putting items in a hash table, or something else?

Comment: @fred: You can poke around in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f4b894c2a2ce16e2) if you're curious.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that was available without using Reflector.

Answer (score 3):

One way you can accomplish this is with `GroupBy`. Group the items by `A`, and use a `SelectMany` to project each group into a flat list again. In the `SelectMany`, check if `A` is `2` and if so `Take(1)`, otherwise return all results for that group. We're using `Take` instead of `First` because the result has to be `IEnumerable`.

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(g => g.A);
var collapsed = grouped.SelectMany(g =>
{
     if (g.Key == 2)
     {
         return g.Take(1);
     }
     return g;
});
```

Comment: `Take(1)` is definitely better than the `First` that I had before.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution (if you insist on LINQ):

```
int a = 2;  
var output = list.GroupBy(o => o.A == a ? a.ToString() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                 .Select(g => g.First())
                 .ToList();
```

Group all items with `A=2` into group with key equal to `2`, but all other items will have unique group key (new guid), so you will have many groups having one item. Then from each group we take first item.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
var newlist = list.Where (l => l.A != 2 ).ToList();
newlist.Add( list.First (l => l.A == 2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to other answers based on `GroupBy` can be [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
// Aggregate lets iterate a sequence and accumulate a result (the first arg)
var list2 = list.Aggregate(new List<Item>(), (result, next) => {
     // This will add the item in the source sequence either
     // if A != 2 or, if it's A == 2, it will check that there's no A == 2
     // already in the resulting sequence!
     if(next.A != 2 || !result.Any(item => item.A == 2)) result.Add(next);  
     return result;
});
```

Comment: Does the result.Any call iterate through the results again for each call?

Comment: @fred Yes, it does. This would work with small sets of items. If you're going to *reduce* 100k or 1M items, it can be a bottleneck... BTW, it doesn't iterate the entire sequence, but until it reaches an item which matches the condition.

Comment: @fred In fact, I was thinking about providing you a `HashSet<T>` approach, which may consist in defining an `IEqualityComparer<T>` using the same condition as `Aggregate` and it should perform a lot of better...

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
list.RemoveAll(l => l.A == 2 && l != list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.A == 2));
```

if you whould like more efficient way it would be:

```
var first = list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.A == 2);
list.RemoveAll(l => l.A == 2 && l != first);
```